# How to make the checkbox disabled?

Tags: javascript, jsp

How can I make the checkbox disabled when they are populated with an array.

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${flightItems}">
    <c:set var="k" value="${k+1}"/> 
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${k}"/></td>
        <td>${item.startPoint}</td>
        <td>${item.endPoint}</td>
        <td><input id="cb" type="checkbox"  name="itemId" value="${item.id}" onchange="check(this)"disabled/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I need to make that by clicking on one checkbox the rest are disabled. While all my attempts led to the fact that all the checkboxes become disabled. Here is my method for checkboxes. I understand my mistake, but I do not know how to fix it. Can you suggest something?

```
function check(self) {
    var a = document.getElementById('cb');
    var checkValue = self.checked;
    for (i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].type == 'checkbox')
            a[i].checked = checkValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should point you in right direction.

First, change from `id` to `class`. IDs are always unique, while class can be same for logical components like this:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${flightItems}">
    <c:set var="k" value="${k+1}"/> 
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${k}"/></td>
        <td>${item.startPoint}</td>
        <td>${item.endPoint}</td>
        <td><input class="cb" type="checkbox"  name="itemId" value="${item.id}" onchange="check(this)"disabled/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Second,

```
function check(self) {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('cb'); // get elements by class name
    var checkValue = self.checked;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { // iterate from 0 instead of 1
        if (a[i] != self && self.checked) // if checkbox is selected.
            a[i].disabled = true; // disable others
    }
}
```

Example:

```html
<input class='cb' type='checkbox' onchange="check(this)" value="1">One
<input class='cb' type='checkbox' onchange="check(this)" value="2">Two
<input class='cb' type='checkbox' onchange="check(this)" value="3">Three
<input class='cb' type='checkbox' onchange="check(this)" value="4">Four
<script>
function check(self) {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('cb'); // get elements by class name
    var checkValue = self.checked;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { // iterate from 0 instead of 1
        if (a[i] != self && self.checked) // if checkbox is selected.
            a[i].disabled = true; // disable others
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @VIRICH hope this helps you

Comment: Yes, it really helped me. But how now to check that if there was a repeated click the checkboxes become enabled?

Comment: @VIRICH - isn't it simple? just play with `if` logic - http://jsfiddle.net/u7dvh0Lq/

Comment: Damn, I was looking for a more complicated solution)) Thanks a lot)

Comment: sure. you can accept it as answer if it solves your problem. :)